# Update failure: "Webmaster name or email missing from Email Configuration settings."

Tags: updating

In the process of updating a site from from EE v2.6.1 to EE 2.7.3, the update stops partway through with this error:

> Webmaster name or email missing from Email Configuration settings.

Has anyone else encountered this error? Does anyone have any advice on how to work around it?

Comment: Does your installation have those fields configured ?

Comment: Yes, they are present in the EE 2.6.1 installation.

Comment: Have you run the install wizard ?

Comment: Yes, the install wizard makes it through the 2.7.2 update, but then chokes at the very end and produces the error message above.

Comment: I just tried again, restarting from the beginning, but ran into the same problem.

Comment: Can you skip the wizard and try (with db backup) a normal update ?

Comment: I'm only familiar with the update process described in the [user guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html), step 6 of which is to run the update wizard. 

Is there another approach that will accomplish the update without running the wizard?

Comment: Hmm...given that the wizard normally gets through the 2.7.2 update before it fails, I thought maybe taking the ud_273.php file out of the /system/installer/updates folder would at least let the process get to EE 2.7.2, at which point I could check various things and attempt the final update to EE 2.7.3, but that didn't work either (the update wizard doesn't get to any of the updates in that case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EllisLab Support helped me figure this one out, but just in case anyone else ever runs into this problem, here was the solution:

It was presumably a third-party add-on that was responsible for the error, and the add-on update process is the next-to-last step the update wizard runs before updating the EE version number in the config.php file.

I just needed to check that the EE 2.7.3 changes were reflected in the database, which meant checking that the following database fields were updated to a length of 75 characters.

- exp_members.email field
- exp_email_cache.from_email
- exp_email_console_cache.recipient

These had, in fact, been updated correctly, so all I needed to do was update the version in the config file to "273," remove the "installer" directory from the server, and log into the control panel to update the add-ons.

Now everything works just fine. Many thanks to Robin Sowell at EllisLab Support for helping me sort this out!